# Passing Data from Observable to a global variable in Ionic 5/Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs-observables

I am working on a messaging app to learn ionic/angular.  I would like to get the message details and then use them in the html template.  However, the way I am currently doing this does not seem to work.  It says that the messageDetails is still undefined.

Here's my inbox-details.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfigService } from '../services/config.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-inbox-detail',
  templateUrl: './inbox-detail.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inbox-detail.page.scss'],
})
export class InboxDetailPage implements OnInit {

  messageDetails = null;

  constructor(private configService: ConfigService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMessageDetails();
  }

  getMessageDetails() {
    let currentId = Data[];

    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((parameter) => {
      currentId = parameter['id'];
    });
    this.messageDetails = this.configService.getMessageDetail(currentId).subscribe((response) => {
      this.messageDetails = response;
    });
    console.log('message deets');
    console.log(this.messageDetails);
  }
}
```

Here is my config.service.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface Messages {}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigService {
  apiUrl = 'https://the-backend-api.com';

  currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentMessagingUser'));
  currentToken = this.currentUser['token'];
  header = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Token ${this.currentToken}`);


  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getInboxMessages() {
    return this.httpClient.get<Messages>(this.apiUrl + '/messages/', {'headers': this.header});
  }

  createMessage(messageTitle, messageBody, messageReceiver) {
    return this.httpClient.post<Messages>(
      this.apiUrl + '/messages/',
      {'title': messageTitle, 'body': messageBody, 'receiver': messageReceiver},
      {'headers': this.header}
    );
  }

  getSentMessages() {
    return this.httpClient.get<Messages>(this.apiUrl + '/messages/sent/', {'headers': this.header});
  }

  deleteMessage(messageId) {
    return this.httpClient.delete<Messages>(this.apiUrl + `/messages/${messageId}/`, {'headers': this.header});
  }

  getMessageDetail(messageId) {
    return this.httpClient.get<Messages>(this.apiUrl + `/messages/${messageId}/`, {'headers': this.header});
  }
}
```

How do I properly save the response from the API call as a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because You set `currentId` after `getMessageDetail` is called. Set component property to

```
messageDetails$ = this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(flatMap(params => this.configService.getMessageDetail(params['id'])))
```

and use `messageDetails$ | async` in view.

It has to work, otherwise check network tab whether it returns data.

Comment: I am able to set the currentId correctly though and get all of the message detail data.  Just once I am out of the function that requests the message details it looks like it is set to null again.

Comment: `this.messageDetails` is set only once on ngOnInit with initial `currentId` and `currentId` is changed in future after every route param change. Both actions are asynchronus and are not connected in any way. You should either create single observable for both like I've proposed or move assigning `this.messageDetails` to `flatMap` after `this.activatedRoute.params`